# remove the hash from the Navigation bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash

I'm loading successfully external content to my div with Jquery, the only problem is that I wish to not  display: "PastURL+#+NewURL" just the NewURL

For example, right now if I click in some of my links I will have: http://mydomain.com/#http://mydomain.com/loaded-content

What I want to show is just: http://mydomain.com/loaded-content

This is my code:

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        jQuery('.portfolio-item a').live('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var link = jQuery(this).attr('href');
            jQuery('#contenthome').fadeOut(500).load(link + ' #content-wrapper', function(){ jQuery('#contenthome').fadeIn(500); });
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
            window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);

        });

    });
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: this is not possible. You could have it be  `http://mydomain.com/#loaded-content`

Comment: Why not just scrollTop to the hash?

Comment: @iliacholly and tfbox, thanks for your quick answers, it's a pity it's not possible, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can rewrite the url in the address bar using the following script:

Notes:

- you can only write paths of the same domain
- this is only supported in modern browsers (like Chrome, FF 5, etc.)

-

```
try {
    if (window.location.search.substring(1).length == 0) { // if no query string
        window.history.pushState('page', browser_title, browser_url);
    }
}
catch (e) { /* browser doesn't support */ }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure Firefox 4 has supports for this too.

Comment: it must, I didn't mention it cause I'm wasn't sure.

Comment: Didn't work, probably is because I'm not a programmer and I don't know where paste that code...

Comment: It won't work if you just copying and pasting my code, you need to change variables (browser_title, browser_url) to those in your code.

Comment: Great! it works! Now I just need to get <?php the_title(); ?> and <?php the_permalink(); ?> (It's implemented on WordPress) for those variables, I will keep searching here. Thanks a lot guys!